# How to display a MySQL blob image in html in django?

Tags: django

I have a mysql blob image in my database and I want to show it in html. I retrieved the blob in my views.py using raw SQL query and passed it to my my html page as a dictionary object.I have not used models so please refrain from giving an answer using models.